# Make PDF display inline instead of separate Acrobat Reader window

Tags: asp.net, pdf, browser

I've got an ASP.NET ashx class that retrieves data from a database, creates a PDF file using iTextSharp, and streams the PDF to the browser. The browser (IE and Firefox at least) is launching Acrobat Reader as a separate window to open the file. I'd like for it to display inline within the browser.

Is that something I can completely control from the server side? I'm already setting the Content-Type header to application/pdf, and I've tried setting Content-Disposition and Content-Length. Nothing so far has worked.

Is there another header I'm missing? Is there something in the PDF itself that tells the browser how to display it? Any other ideas?

Comment: No, no, no, it's my browser and I'll view PDFs where I want to view them. Okay, I'm sure this is for an internal corporate website. Still, I find this annoying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting the content-disposition and content-type headers should do it, but you might also need to call `Response.ClearHeaders()` to clear other headers that have been set.

Also, try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the actual headers and content from the response and compare them to those from a site that works like you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an ashx (web handler) try this:-

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=Something.pdf")
```

Comment: I thought that would work, too, but it didn't. I also tried setting the content length.

Comment: It's working for me on IIS6, IE7, ASP.NET3.5.  Hmmm... Have you tried the minimal case in a few browsers?  If so I'll add my full source to the answer.

Comment: Christopher, it would have worked for you because of your client side settings for Adobe or whatever PDF viewer you are using.  If you have a different version, or have show in browser disabled, it won't work.

Comment: If you show in browser disabled in Adobe Reader or whatever clearly it won't respect the content-disposition header from the web server.  Otherwise it should.

Answer (score 4):

OK, turns out it was a stupid question, but I'm glad I asked it because I had never heard of Fiddler (which led me to the answer, which is why I'm accepting tspauld's answer). The PDF is generated by a web service that serves the file to a couple of different front-end sites. I was setting the content disposition to `inline` in the service, but that didn't matter, because the browser never got that header; it got the header from the front-end site (which was `attachment`). I changed it in the front-end site and that fixed it.

So the answer is that you have to have `Content-Type=application/pdf` and `Content-Disposition=inline; filename=Something.pdf`, as others have said.

Answer (score 1):

Try generating them into your page using html OBJECT.

```
<OBJECT WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=480>
    <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="<%=filePath%>"> 
    <EMBED SRC=<%=filename.pdf%> WIDTH=1000 HEIGHT=680> 
        <NOEMBED> PDF should have displayed here!</NOEMBED> 
        </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

If you need to stream the response with an ashx instead of being able to return an aspx, I think you may be out of luck.

Otherwise, I believe the settings to show in browser or not, is completely client driven and out of your hands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I want them to have the option of saving the PDF. Will embedding work for that?

Comment: @jmgant - when the PDF is embedded, the Acrobat ActiveX does have a "Save" icon in its toolbar.

Comment: To be honest, I am not positive without testing.  That said, even if it doesn't, you could easily add a Download link or button to your page.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have a sample in one of my works that is what you need:

```
<cc1:ShowPdf ID="ShowPdf1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"  BorderWidth="0px"
        Height="750px" Style="z-index: 103; "
        Width="750px"/>
```

and in server side :

```
  ShowPdf1.FilePath = String.Format("~/Handlers/Pdf.ashx?id={0}#view=FitH&page=1&pagemode=none&navpanes=1", myPublicationId);
```

I place here also some code from my PDF Handler :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    byte[] bytes = YourBinaryContent;

    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
    {
        writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

Anyway If my post doesn't seem clear to you, have a look at this sample [How to Display PDF documents with ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/PDF-View-Custom-Control.aspx)

Comment: Is ShowPdf a custom control? What does setting its FilePath property do?

Comment: Yes. FilePath instructs my control which PDF file (saved in database) to show, and how to show it passing the needed parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think this header will do what you want

```
Content-type: application/pdf
```

Since you say that is not working, then I suspect it is a configuration setting on the client side.

Check your installed version of Adobe Acrobat. There is a setting in preferences for "Internet" and a checkbox that says "Display PDF in Browser".

--
bmb

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've set my Acrobat Reader to display inline but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I've been to other PDF pages that display inline in my browser, but the one I'm serving doesn't. So I don't think it's strictly a client issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on using the embed tag to do it:http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2007/08/using_the_html_embed_tag_to_di.html

Answer (score -1):

If you have the budget, my company sells a set of products that includes an [AJAX based image viewer](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/thinclient/default.aspx) that will let you view the PDF pages in line without Acrobat at all.  In its simplest form, it is just a viewer, but you can layer in interactivity as you need.