# Show file in web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a response which contains a PDF file

```
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
Stream pdf = res.GetResponseStream();
```

I want to show this PDF on web browser without save it in a file. How could I do that?

Comment: [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859815/make-pdf-display-inline-instead-of-separate-acrobat-reader-window)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code and works fine.

```
public static void SendDataByteFileToClient(HttpContext context, byte[] data, string fileName, string contentType, bool clearHeaders = true)
        {

            if (clearHeaders)
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            }

            context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
            context.Response.ContentType = contentType;

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());

            if (BrowserHelper.IsOfType(BrowserTypeEnum.IE) && BrowserHelper.Version < 9)
            {
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
                context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);//IE set to not cache
                context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();//Firefox/Chrome not to cache
                context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow); //for safe measure expire it immediately
            }

            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
            }

            context.Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
Stream pdfdata = res.GetResponseStream();
string path = pdfdata.ToString();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);

    if (buffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: But pdf is not a string

Comment: pdf is response we getting there not in terms of original pdf

Comment: i hope that is common sense. but for your happiness i edit that.

Comment: next time i keep in that i write whole program step by step without any single semicolon missing.