# stream pdf from MemoryStream

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I'm streaming a pdf from an .ashx file to the browser using the following code:

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.Charset = "";
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=test.pdf");
context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

where context comes from:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

All works well when using Chrome or Firefox and it displays on the browser.  But when I use IE 11 I get a blank screen.  If I go to Adobe Reader->Edit->Preference->Internet and uncheck "Display PDF in browser" then from IE it opens Adobe Reader and shows the PDF properly.  But as soon as I unchecked "Display PDF in browser" then it just shows the blank screen:

[image]

If I go to IE "Manage Add-ons" it shows that Adobe is enabled:

[image]

I've seen other post but nothing seems to work.  I'm thinking its an IE thing since Chrome and Firefox works and with IE displays if I don't have it load on the browser.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**Update: Fiddler Data:**

Here is what I got from Fiddler.  Nothing stands out between Chrome and IE except that IE doesnt work:

Chrome: 
Request:

GET /FileDownloadHandler.ashx?session=agenda_item_number_download&id=6079&downloadtoken=635685165181990000 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost/FileDownload.aspx?session=agenda_item_number_download&id=6079
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=n3r0p3lgrnsherwl0iid3ser

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 150173
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=test.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: DownloadSessionToken=635685165181990000; path=/
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcTUNXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbnNcU291cmNlXE1vaGF2ZUNvdW50eVxGaWxlRG93bmxvYWRIYW5kbGVyLmFzaHg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 17:15:19 GMT

IE:

Request:

GET /FileDownloadHandler.ashx?session=agenda_item_number_download&id=6079&downloadtoken=635685164869660000 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://localhost/FileDownload.aspx?session=agenda_item_number_download&id=6079
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=1ekxziruzsstknjubyugl3ur

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 150173
Content-Type: application/pdf
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=test.pdf
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: DownloadSessionToken=635685164869660000; path=/
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcTUNXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbnNcU291cmNlXE1vaGF2ZUNvdW50eVxGaWxlRG93bmxvYWRIYW5kbGVyLmFzaHg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 17:14:47 GMT

**Fix Update**

Ok it seems like its an Adobe Reader problem.  I found the problem because eventually my stream would produce a 103:103 error.  After doing some searches I found where it says to do the following:

Launch Adobe Reader
In "Adobe Preferences" open menu "General"
Untick (uncheck) the setting "Enable Protected Mode at startup"
If that doesn't do anything uninstall the software, run adobe cleaner tool and then reinstall the software.

And now its working properly.  Ive included the [CC Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs5-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) in case anyone wants to use it.

Comment: Looking at this related post, seems like it might be worth using Fiddler to doublecheck the headers, make sure there is nothing specifying attachment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859815/make-pdf-display-inline-instead-of-separate-acrobat-reader-window?rq=1

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The page in the screenshot is FileDownload.aspx but you say the PDF is streamed from FileDownloadHandler.ashx.  Is the handler loaded in an iframe or object tag?

Comment: Your right I accidentally took the wrong screen shot.  I have updated my original question to include the correct screenshot.  Also I added the error that Adobe gives

Answer (score 0):

I posted my answer in the my original post.  Seems like this issue is an Adobe Reader bug.